# How do I pass ILogger<T> from a razor page to another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am trying to setup logging in my server side Blazor app.

Here is a class I have that gets data from an API:

```
public class LicenseService
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LicenseService(ILogger<LicenseService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<List<Licenses>> GetLicensesAsync()
    {                
        List<Licenses> model = null;
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
        var task = await client.GetAsync("https://my.domain/v1/licenses");
        if(!task.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Result was {task.StatusCode}");
        }
        _logger.LogError($"Result was {task.StatusCode}");
        var jsonString = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Licenses>>(jsonString);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Here is a .razor page that calls that class. What do I pass in to `new LicenseService();`? I can't instantiate a new instance of `Ilogger` or `Ilogger<LicenseService>`.

```
private async Task<List<Licenses>> GetLicenseData()
{
    LicenseService service = new LicenseService();
    var licenseData = await service.GetLicensesAsync();
    return licenseData;
}
```

I'm sure this is because I don't really understand how dependency injection works in dotnet core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, if you are using dependency injection as it's designed, you wouldn't be creating a new instance of LicenseService there at all, but rather *injecting the dependency*, as the name suggests.

During your Startup, you might have the following service registration (or something similar).

```
services.AddScoped<LicenseService>();
```

Within your Razor page's constructor, the service container can now automatically resolve this dependency for you, taking care of all of *its* dependencies, too, assuming those dependencies were also registered.

```
public class YourPageModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly LicenseService _licenseService;

    public YourPageModel (LicenseService licenseService)
    {
        _licenseService = licenseService;
    }

    public async Task<List<Licenses>> GetLicenseData()
    {
        var licenseData = await _licenseService.GetLicensesAsync();
        return licenseData;
    }
}
```

**Update**:

The service can be injected into your Blazor component with DI using this syntax at the top:

```
@inject LicenseService licenseService
```

And then referenced as `licenseService` in your method. See this link for an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/build-your-first-blazor-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dependency-injection

Comment: I think I have also confused Blazor with Razor, as I do not have a PageModel class. I just have a LicenseInfo.razor file.

Comment: I misunderstood where your method was sitting on first glance. Added an update to show how to inject in your Blazor component, although the service registration piece and general practice is the same.